# Stuck in World 2-4 in Midnight Leaves

Tags: midnight-leaves

["Midnight Leaves"](http://www.igf.com/php-bin/entry2012.php?id=703) is a puzzle-game which takes part in the IGF 2012. [A demo is available on the author's website](http://roancontreras.zxq.net/games/midnight_leaves.html). I am currently stuck in World 2-4.

The aim is to "release" all the yellow leaves, and we are allowed to move only once on each tile, except if we have special power-ups. The main character is the yellow square. The dark grey square is a power-up which allows to move several times on the four following tiles. The circles launch fireballs after four steps. The red cross cancels any power-up.

[image: World 2-4 level]

And there is this new power-up with a crossed-out leaf.

It seems I cannot understand the meaning of the hint:

> Some leaves will free if you hit a fireball on its crystal.

What am I supposed to do?

---

**Edit**

If you want to try this level yourself, just create a new file called `Data.mlgc` containing:

```
[Data]
World=2
Level=4
```

This will give you the same savefile as I currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a matter of speed in the last part. :'(

The solution is the path in light blue.

[image: solution]